# At what age an heir become the ruler?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

A neighbor country is led by a regency council. I need more prestige points to claim the throne, and I'm asking me how much time I have before their heir become the ruler.

**At what age a heir becomes the ruler ?**

Can it vary depending of the government type ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**15 years old**, this applies to all countries with hereditary government. In election based governments, you simply elect a new ruler.

Though, of course your old ruler has to die first. 
It's entirely possible, that your ruler lives till 80 and has an heir who is 75.

If your heir is younger than 15, when your ruler dies you will have to put up with a regency council, until he comes of age (this means no offensive wars, -2 legitimacy/year and the council usually has weak stats).